# Where can I download The Resistance rules?

Tags: the-resistance

I've been googling around and cannot find the Resistance official web site where I can download the rules.  Does the site even exist?  Where can I read the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [publisher's page.](http://indieboardsandcards.com/resistance.php).

The link to the rules is a tiny button right under the red navigation menu on the left hand of the screen.

Comment: The page does not seem to have them any longer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's one](http://www.boardgameguys.ie/sites/bggnew/files/The_Resistance_rules_english.pdf) I found, though it is slightly different from what I have in my box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a pdf. Pretty tough to find.

http://www.boardgameguys.ie/sites/bggnew/files/The_Resistance_rules_english.pdf